# How would I go about converting CorelDraw files to Adobe Creative Suite

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, corel-draw

My company has used CorelDraw for the past 20 years. Many artwork files.
Corel sadly can't cope with the artworks we are creating so we are thinking of moving to the Adobe Creative suite.

My question is...is there an efficient way of converting our CDR files to work with the Adobe suite?

Comment: What is what you say Corel can't cope with? What is the artwork you have? Ilustrations? Logos? Magazine documents?

Comment: You don't have to convert them. Adobe Illustrator can open CDR files, so too can some other vector software, such as Inkscape (which is free). Of course that's not to say they will open them perfectly. There might be compatibility issues.  Another possibility is to export files from CorelDraw into another common vector format such as PDF, EPS, SVG etc.